# How can you find out the information about the client used to open an email?

Tags: email, tracking

How can you track what clients (device, browser, email client, ect...) a user opens an email with in realtime without using Google Analytics or other pieces of software?

Do you embed an image and then check the header? or is there another solution.

I know this will only be possible if the user has html activated, but lets go with the premise that they do.

Comment: You want to do it *without* software? What does that leave?

Comment: I mean a self coded solution using php/java or other